# How to distinguish the same named helper methods in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have created  helper function(link_to_alert) in two different helpers

1. app/helpers/posts_helper.rb

   app/helpers/students_helper.rb

Now calling my helper function `link_to_alert` from `app/views/student/index.html.haml`

Problem is the view calling the same function present in `app/helpers/posts_helper.rb`

How do I call the helper function present in `app/helpers/students_helper.rb` from my  `app/views/student/index.html.haml` view?

Comment: Modulename.definitionname would work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since all helpers are included into all controllers by default the most common way is to name the functions differently, for example `link_to_alert_posts` and `link_to_alert_students`.

The second way is to disable including all helpers and pick the ones you need in a controller.

```
config.action_controller.include_all_helpers = false

class PostsController
  helper :posts
end

class StudentsController
  helper :students
end
```

In this case all views rendered by Posts Controller will have the function from Posts Helper, and for Students Controller - from Students Helper.

The third way is to use module_function and prefix all calls with the helper module name.
I have never seen this used particularly with Rails helpers though.

```
module StudentsHelper
  module_function

  def link_to_alert
  end
end

StudentsHelper.link_to_alert
```

Another approach would be using presenters or decorators, but that is a totally different topic.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put different names, `link_to_alert_posts`, `link_to_alert_students`?
And btw you can call it by putting the Module name and the function name.